# Replace (and backup) Method dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, replace

I need to change a specific property dynamically and have been using this snipplet:

```
var _oldMethod = typeof(TypeName).GetProperty("OldProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetMethod;
var _newMethod = typeof(OwnTypeName).GetProperty("NewProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetMethod;
ReplaceMethod(_oldMethod, _newMethod);
```

...

```
private static unsafe void ReplaceMethod(MethodInfo _oldMethod, MethodInfo _newMethod)
{
    var _oldMethodAddress = new IntPtr((int*)_oldMethod.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2);
    var _destination = (uint*)_oldMethodAddress.ToPointer();
    *destination = (uint)_newMethod.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt32();
}
```

Unfortunately this required some decompiling with recreating the original property. What I am looking for now is a a possibility to duplicate and kind of backup the original method and dynamically replace the old method with the new one or restore the original one.

Has anyone an idea how to implement this?

**Edit:**
I may should have clarified my situation further:

```
public static class ClassName
{
    public static bool Property
    {
      get
      {
        // Conditions
      }
    }
}
```

I can't access ClassName and need to force Property to false in specific situations and need to replace it to the original return value in other situations. I have been using the ReplaceMethod above mentioned but don't want to decompile and rebuild Property from scratch (instead some kind of backup of the original Property)

Comment: Can you give us a little background on why you want to do this?

Comment: Just a FYI, a IntPtr will not fit in a `uint` on 64 bit machines.

Comment: Added some further information

Comment: Funny was gonna ask if you had access to `ClassName` as there are better ways if you did. I take it you need to have other classes that you can't access benefit from your hack as well? If not, you could use a shim.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are handling properties instead of methods.

One easy approach to do this is to replace your properties type by Func<> and this will keep what you're wanting to do easier.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new A();

    a.Property = Method1;
    Console.WriteLine(a.Property.Invoke());

    a.Property = Method2;
    Console.WriteLine(a.Property.Invoke());

    Func<string> oldMethod = a.Property;
    Console.WriteLine(oldMethod.Invoke());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class A
{
    public Func<string> Property { get; set; }
}

private static string Method1()
{
    return "Method1";
}

private static string Method2()
{
    return "Method2";
}
```

You can change the method as many times as you want and also keep the old one in one variable.

Comment: The property type is an ordinary bool and I can't access class (as written in Edit)